# Accessing the column headers from a view panel on an Xpage in Lotus Notes

Tags: xpages

Is there any way i can get the handle of View Column Header of a view panel on an Xpage?
I have a view panel.It has View Column Header and View Column in it.There is no programmatic way to get the handle of these.Any idea?

Comment: what are you trying to do with this ? perhaps there is an inbuilt way to do what your trying to do and just thinking about it the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your view column header's ID is `viewColumnHeader1`, then you can get the handle of that column in SSJS using below command.

```
var columnHeader:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumnHeader = getComponent("viewColumnHeader1");
```

But I would second with Simon McLoughlin, perhaps you can look into the Properties for View Column Header.